# Sorting an array that is the result of a $resource call in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm trying to get the results of an API call and save it to `$scope.segments`, so that later I can sort the array using `$scope.segments.sort()`

However, since `$scope.segments = SegmentsService.getSegments(jobId);` does an async call, `$scope.segments` is `undefined` and the sorting never works.

Struggling with this the full day. How can I resolve this?

Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('appApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $filter, JobsFactory, SegmentsFactory, SegmentsService) {

    var jobId = $routeParams.id;

    // gets the segments from the API
    $scope.segments = SegmentsService.getSegments(jobId);

    // returns 'undefined', because $resource has not populated the 'segments' array yet
    console.log($scope.segments);

    // returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined", because $scope.segment doesn't exist (yet)
    $scope.segments.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.sequence - b.sequence;
    });

  });
```

Here's my service:

```
angular.module('appApp')
  .service('SegmentsService', function (SegmentsFactory) {

    var segments = [];

    this.getSegments = function(jobId) {
      SegmentsFactory.query({ job_id: jobId }).$promise.then(function(data) {
        segments = data;
        return segments;
      }, function(err) {
        //fail
      });
    };

  });
```

And last, here's my factory:

```
angular.module('appApp')
  .factory('SegmentsFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/segments/:id');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how promises work :)

I'm a big fan of [Promises in AngularJS, Explained as a Cartoon](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html) for that matter :)

Here is working code for your use case.

```
// service: return the promise
.service('SegmentService', function (...) {    
     this.getSegments = function(jobId) {
         return SegmentsFactory.query({ job_id: jobId }).$promise;
     };
});

// controller
.controller('MainCtrl', function (...) {
    SegmentsService.getSegments(jobId).then(function(segments) {
        segments.sort(function(a, b) { return ...; });
        $scope.segments = segments;
    });

});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Crying of happiness. Reading that cartoon now. Thanks buddy!